# How to place text at the bottom when there's predefined height!

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

This should be incredibly trivial, but it's not. I have a predefined height for an anchor, and I would like to place the text at the bottom.

```
<li><a class="my-text">My Text</a></li>
```

I used the following CSS, which does not work. The text still appears at the top.

```
a.my-text {
     background-color:#cccc;
     height:50px;
     vertical-align:bottom;
     width:100px;
}
```

The idea is: I want to align text to the bottom, but if there is text that is longer than one line, I want the over flow to go to the top, not push everything else down... any ideas of how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done using css and the html you provide. If you put an extra span in the anchor, it can be done:

```
a.my-text {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}
a.my-text span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: you mean position: absolute. `position: relative; bottom: 0;` won't move the element anywhere

Comment: Right. I'm a dumbass. Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bottom:0px` with `position:absolute` in anchor.

**HTML**

```
<li><a class="my-text">My Text</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

a.my-text {
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#cccc;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZQC6/2/).

Answer (score 1):

It definitely would not work, because `<a>` anchors are inline tags, therefore assigning them heights and widths is useless. The `vertical-align` property determines the positioning of inline elements with respect to the line they're in, not the vertical position of the text. (See http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align) As far as I understand what you are requesting cannot be done. However, there are alternatives, as suggested above, to achieve similar effects.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the anchor won't respond to height/width because it is an inline element. If you you add a **{display: block}** to the anchor it's now a block element, but, as I recall, **vertical-align** doesn't work on the contents of block elements. This was the easiest way I could think of using **display: table-cell**.

```
a.my-text {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 200px; width: 100px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Scott, I've used that solution a while before, but it caused a weird outcome for the rest of my CSS... I'll give it another try and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to get rid of the height rule on the anchor tag and use something like `padding-top: 45px` on the `li`

Comment: No, that would not work. Because if the anchor text occupies more than one line, then the contents below the anchor would be pushed down instead of the anchor text being pushed up.