# Have <a> text move down during CSS padding transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to become more comfortable with `CSS` styling and while making a test site, I ran into some behavior with an `anchor` tag and a transition that I can't seem to change. I added padding to the link and when clicked, I want to increase the padding on the bottom and have the text move down with the bottom border. While the padding does increase when the tag is `active`, the text stays put instead of moving down during the transition.

After reading through some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928849/css-how-to-make-a-text-align-bottom) [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033553/align-the-text-to-the-bottom-of-the-a-tag) [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483738/how-to-place-text-at-the-bottom-when-theres-predefined-height)(there are more), it seems like the general idea is to add `relative` or `absolute` positioning on the anchor tag and either set the containing div's `display` property to `table-cell` or set the `bottom` attribute to 0. These solutions don't work I assume because I'm not changing the height but I'm changing the padding.

**A small example**

```css
.SiteButtons a {
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.SiteButtons a:active {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="SiteButtons">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
</div>
```

Is this something that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusted CSS:

```
.SiteButtons {
    display: flex;
}

.SiteButtons a {
    transition: padding 0.3s ease;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}

.SiteButtons a:active {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xfdpxedf/1/

Comment: Awesome. If I add that is there a way to stop elements below it from moving too? I didn't want to dump a bunch of code on here, but [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7565766g/) that basically shows what I'm currently working with.

Comment: When the nav items expand they *grow in height*, pushing down the elements beneath. To prevent the elements below from moving you need to reserve space for the extra height from the start: http://jsfiddle.net/7565766g/1/

Comment: _Ohhh_. That makes sense, the border you added is a nice visual for it. Thank you for the help and information!